# How can I read/write to an Excel template (.xltx) from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have ReportTemplate.xltx in my Visual Studio solution/project. How can I read and write data from my ExcelReport.DataGrid using my ReportTemplate.xltx template in my solution?

Basically I want to put the data in my datagrid into a new excel file using my report template.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from Microsoft allows you to work with the XSLX files using c# without requiring Excel to be installed.

I assume it also covers XLTX files (but I haven't confirmed it myself).